# Prestashop theme copy not shown

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm new in prestashop and try to create my own theme using default. My prestashop version is 1.6.0.9. So i'm coping contents of `/themes/default-bootstrap` to `/themes/test`. Then I go to backoffice -> preferences -> themes and I see only default theme and then themes from shop. But don't see my "test" theme. How I should do to choose my newly created theme?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer - I use apache 2.4.9, and this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

should be:

```
<FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem with 1.6.0.9 and 1.6.0.8.
What file you change?

Comment: themes/.htaccess
modules/.htaccess